# Parsing .py files performances with mod_wsgi / django / rest_framework

Tags: python, django, performance, django-rest-framework, django-wsgi

I'm using apache with mod_wsgi on a debian jessie, python3.4, django and django REST framework to power a REST web service.

I'm currently running performance tests. My server is a KS-2 (http://www.kimsufi.com/fr/serveurs.xml) with 4Gb of RAM and an Atom N2800 processor (1.8GHz, 2c/4t). My server already runs plenty of little services, but my load average does not exceed 0.5 and I usually have 2Gb of free RAM. I'm giving those context informations because maybe the performances I describe below is normal in context of this hardware support.

I'm quite new to python powered web services and don't really know what to except in term of performances. I used firefox's network monitor to test the duration of a request.

I've set up a test environnement with django rest framework's first example (http://www.django-rest-framework.org/). When I go to url http://myapi/users/?format=json I have to wait ~1600 ms. If I check the response multiple times in a short period of time it goes down go 60ms. However, as soon as I wait more than ~5 secs, the average time is 1600ms.

My application has about 6k lines of python and includes some django librairies in INSTALLED_APPS (django-cors-headers, django-filter, django-guardian, django-rest-swagger). When I perform the same kind of tests (on a comparable view returning a list of my users) on it I get 6500/90ms.

My data do not require a lot of ressources to retrieve (django-debug-toolbar shows me that my SQL queries take <10ms to perform). So I'm not sure what is going on under the hood but I guess all .py files need to be periodically parsed or .pyc to be read. If it's the case, is it possible to get rid of this behaviour ? I mean, in a production environnement where I know I won't edit often my files. Or if it's not the case, to lower the weight of the first call.

Note : I've read django's documentation about cache (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/cache/), but in my application my data (which do not seem to require a lot of ressources) is susceptible to change often. I guess caching does not help for the source code of an application, am I wrong ?

Thanks

Comment: Servers do not "periodically" parse files; and they only need to be loaded once per process.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I guess all .py files need to be periodically parsed or .pyc to be read

.py files are only parsed (and compiled to bytecode .pyc files) when there's no matching .pyc file or the .py file is newer than the .pyc. Also, the .pyc files are only loaded once per process.

Given your symptom, chances are your problem is mostly with your server's settings. First make sure you're in daemon mode (https://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/QuickConfigurationGuide#Delegation_To_Daemon_Process), then tweak your settings accroding to your server hardware and application's needs ( https://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/ConfigurationDirectives#WSGIDaemonProcess)

Comment: I read again https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/howto/deployment/wsgi/modwsgi/ where it's indeed recommanded to use daemon mode. But it there is no mention about performances and with a such difference I really though the problem was somewhere else.

Comment: Daemon mode will not improve raw performance, but it gives you more control on the processes life cycle. Note that if you only hit your application once a day chances are the processes (whether in embedded or daemon mode) will be either asleep or just dead at that time so you'll still have some latency on the first request.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like your Apache does remove the Python processes from the memory after a while. mod_wsgi loads the Python interpreter and files into Apache which is slow. However you should be able to tune it so it keeps them into memory.